# Escape slash in preg_regex or do I have to?

Tags: php, regex

I have this text and expression, I tried everything and it doesn't work. If I remove the slash at the end then it works. According to preg_quote manual the only chars I need to escape are these:

> . \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -

I tried to escape the last slash with a backslash `\/` and also try `\\/` but still it doesn't work.

```
Sample text:  song
file="http://mehangcuugiup.net/images/radio/2013/t4/Thu Ba ngay
16-4-2013.mp3" title="Thu Ba ngay 16-4-2013"/;

NOT Match Expression: $exp = '@song file="(http.+?\.mp3)"
title=".+?(\d+\-\d+\-\d{4})"/@i';

Good Expression: $exp = '@&lt;song file="(http.+?\.mp3)"
title=".+?(\d+\-\d+\-\d{4})"@i';
```

I know I can just remove the last slash to get my data but this issue has been bother me for while now, I like to know the cause of it.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Your "good expression" also has `&lt;` before it. Is that significant?

Comment: just to make the question cleaner I removed the two carets around the sample text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to escape the `/` if you used it as the delimiter.  In your case, the delimiter is `@`, so you don't need to escape `/` (but, you *do* need to escape `@`).

```
<?php

$song = 'song file="http://mehangcuugiup.net/images/radio/2013/t4/Thu Ba ngay 16-4-2013.mp3" title="Thu Ba ngay 16-4-2013"/';
$exp = '@song file="(http.+?\.mp3)" title=".+?(\d+\-\d+\-\d{4})"/@i';

if(preg_match($exp, $song, $match) === 1){
    var_dump($match);
}
```

DEMO: http://ideone.com/iuunxe

Comment: I don't know what went wrong, I tried that before and it didn't yield any result.  I tried your code and it works, may be there is a typo somewhere in my code. Anyhoo thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape that slash, using double quotes `"\/"`.`

```
$exp = "@song file=\"(http.+?.mp3)\" title=\".+?(\d+-\d+-\d{4})\"\/@i";
```

Comment: I actually don't see why that would be necessary, as the OP used `@` as a delimiter.

Comment: Oh, i see. So, i failed on answer.